# Local DB and syncing of new messages in a chatting app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, architecture, chat

I am a bit of a bind when it comes to this topic. Here's my situation, I have a discord-like style of the app where you join chat rooms. I now have the issue of how to handle and use a local DB in conjunction with the remote DB. As I'd only load the newest X messages of the current DB and then if the user scrolls get the other X and so on. But where does a local DB come into the picture? For example, I stored in the DB messages from 10 AM - 12 AM, should I get the oldest message from the local DB and skip the timeframe in the remote DB when requesting the data? What if someone deleted/ edited a message? From my current standpoint, it really seems that just having a remote DB is the way to go

Using Nodejs Typescript and MongoDB for the server and the client is a Kotlin multiplatform app and I have access to a SQL DB on the client if necessary.

Also anyhow I approach this, since this is a chatting App and I already have an established Websocket connection, would loading messages and receiving them via the Websocket make sense, or should I make a REST endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your localdb is effectively a cache, and you should treat it as such.  Now that you have a cache, you have another problem, cache invalidation.  Worse, since each client has it's own, you have a distributed cache invalidation issue.

You can probably sidestep a lot of this by making message immutable, and having a REPLACES_ID and an IS_DELETED field which allows an "edit" to really be an add which then from a UI standpoint replaces another existing message..  This will at least give you something fairly computable from a cursor standpoint.

Ideally your ID field is an increasing numeric sequence that allows simple queries like "Give me X messages from this room where ID is greater than [[The last id in your cache]]"  If no data is returned, your local DB has all the data, otherwise take data from the query and populate your local database to bring these messages in.

Scrolling is more complicated, but in general can be ignored, nobody scrolls (statistically irrelevant number of people go to page 2).  I'd recommend if someone scrolls just wipe the local database past the first page and go back to the remote server for X records BEFORE your current page's first record.

Comment: Gonna put the LocalDB on the backburner for now, doesn't seem 100% worth it or needed at the moment. Thank you for the response. Will wait if someone else gives their input and accept your answer